# Retrieve same type of values with added to that value from database in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[Here is the database structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCag2.png)

Now I want to retrieve Hindi subject marks as 50 i.e. (10+40 = 50) as well as English (124) and Sanskrit (73).

Marks should be retrieved in this manner that same subject marks must be added first and then retrieve where `examID` is `EXM1CAM` or something else.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy will solve your problem. We need to add marks but the addition should be limited by the subject name. So, we will GROUPBY subjectName and SUM by marks.

> Select subjectName, SUM(marks) from MarksTable WHERE examID='EXM1CAM'
>   GROUPBY subjectName

Comment: Thanks, it's working. (`GROUPBY` should be `GROUP BY` in your answer)

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake @SambhavKhare